Applied Project - Controlling Red Blood Cell Loss during Surgery
This is the following question in Chapter 3 - Differentiation Rules in James Stewart's Calculus Book
I solved it and I want to know if I am right.
Here is my solution
$$
b_0 = 5
$$
Since rate of RBC loss is proportional to vol of RBC, then
$$
\frac{db}{dt} = k\cdot b(t)
$$
$$
b(t) = b_0 \cdot e^{kt} = 5 \cdot e^{kt}
$$
At $t = 4$ hours, half the blood has been lost,
$$
b(4) = 50\% \cdot 5 = 2.5 = b_0 \cdot e^{4k} = 2.5 \cdot e^{4k}
$$
$$
e^{4k} = \frac{2.5}{5} = 0.5
$$
$$
\ln(e^{4k}) = \ln(0.5) = -0.693
$$
$$
4k = -0.693
$$
$$
k = \frac{-.693}{4} = -0.1732
$$
So the final equation is
$$
b(t) = 2.5 \cdot e^{-0.1732t}
$$
Is my approach correct? Can someone help me for a solution for this problem? Because if we know that after the end of 4 hours, the male patient loses 2.5L, we don't even need to know the rate at which the blood loses right?

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info
